# height:100% not working inside flexbox with flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The blue box should be 100% height. It works when I set a pixel height for `div.a`, but unfortunately this is not an option for the real world case.

This probably explains everything:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrVEpB

```css
.a{
  background-color:red;
  display:flex;
}
.b1{
  flex-grow:0;
  background-color:green;
}
.b2{
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color:yellow;
  height:100%;
}

.c{
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b1">
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="b2">
      <div class="c">
          miksi et ole full height saatana
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with height:100% on c, it takes the height of it's parent. But there is no height or the height of 100% of it's parent isn't the whole screen..

Comment: remove the `height:100%` in `.b2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need percentage heights to achieve this layout. It can be built with flex properties alone:

```css
.a {
  display: flex; 
  background-color: red;
}
.b1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.b2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.c {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b1">
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
    <p>hurr durr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b2">
    <div class="c">
      miksi et ole full height saatana
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If using percentage heights is a must, then consider the proper implementation:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Comment: I think this behavior is strange (but all browsers seems to do so). How come 100 % inside a "flex-grow" element does not become 100 % of its calculated size?

Comment: @einord, the complete explanation is in the link references at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a height of 100% to the div.a, because the div.c and it's height of 100% take the height of it's parent. But when there isn't any height, it could not work with 100%...https://jsfiddle.net/h2yvoeL0/1/`enter code here`

Cheers.